# Endpoint as variable in SoapUI 5 pro

Tags: soapui, testcase

I'm struggling with creating following test case:

1. GET /businesses - returns list of all businesses in the system
2. GET /businesses/{bussinessID}/messages - returns all messages for particular business. Where {bussinessID} - id of one of the businesses from the first step

I'm wondering if I can achieve this and determine endpoint as a variable and send value of endpoint using property transfer or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dynamic property directly in the requests template parameter {bussinessID}.

```
${x#ResponseAsXml#y}
```

Where x = the test step name of the call you want to reference and y = xpath that specifies the node value you want to pull.